# question about holomorphic & injective functions / Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In my professor's lecture notes it states:

***An injective holomorphic function (also called schlicht function) $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ always defines a biholomorphic (holormorphic and bijective) mapping onto the image $f(D)$, such that the inverse mapping is also holormorphic.***

So from this I'd understand that injective and holormorphic is automatically biholormorphic?

But in the proof of the Riemann Mapping Theorem, the following statement can be found.

***Let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a schlicht function with $f(0)=0$, which is not surjective, then there is a schlicht function $\tilde{f} : D \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ with
$\tilde{f}(0) = 0$ and $\vert \tilde{f}'(0) \vert > \vert f'(0) \vert$***

So I'm really confused, if schlicht functions are per defintion biholomorphic, how can there be a schlicht function which is not surjective? where is my error here?

Comment: A schlicht function $f : D \to \mathbb{D}$ is biholomorphic from $D$ to $f(D)$, but $f(D)$ can be a strict subset of $\Bbb D$.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you so much for this clarification, now I understand the argumentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: D \to \Bbb D$ is schlicht (holomorphic and injective) and $f(D)$ is a strict subset of $\Bbb D$, then $f$ is a biholomorphic mapping from $D$ to $f(D)$, but $f$ is not surjective.